# Remove painted over glow in the dark stars?

Tags: painting

I moved into a new home where the owner painted over some of those glow in the dark stickers on the ceiling. Because they're painted over, I can't simply scrape them off and they still glow through the paint. Any ideas on how to get rid of these things? I'd prefer to get rid of them (or at least make it look like they're gone) than just keep adding coats of paint.

Comment: paint it black, then back to white.

Comment: Can I just say ... Animals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite all of the good suggestions, none of them worked and the labor was getting to be pretty painful; the stars wouldn't come off for anything and there were simply too many.

I ultimately decided to mix some gray primer up with some drywall mud and do a couple of think coats over the ceiling. This buried them and started to hide the glow. After sanding the ceiling smooth, I did another coat of the gray primer and a final two coats of ceiling flat white.

They're gone now.

Comment: Not gone, only hidden.

Comment: Very good point.

Comment: Dark Star - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Star_(song) -  **"Dark star crashes
pouring its light
into ashes"  -  "shall we go,
you and I
While we can?
Through
the transitive nightfall
of diamonds"** -  http://artsites.ucsc.edu/gdead/agdl/darkstar.html

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're going to have to complicated-ly scrape those stars off! Seriously, though, you're right: it would take a fair amount of paint to stop the glowing, and even more paint to build up enough height to bury the stars completely.

The paint entombing the stars is most likely to be of the latex variety. This stuff is somewhat stretchy and rubbery, so to minimize peeling the paint away from the ceiling it'll be important to cut the paint around the star. Use a small and sharp hobby/craft knife to trace the outline of every star. Use light pressure -- you only need to cut through the paint film that's actually *over* the star, and it'll really be best if you can avoid damaging the paper facing of the drywall behind all the layers of paint.

With the perimeter of the stars cut free the next step is to lift them off the surface. You'll need some kind of prying tool. If the stars are just thin stickers then the knife itself may be adequate. If the stars are the thicker rigid plastic type then another tool may be better: a chisel, a putty knife, or some kind of scraping tool.

After the stars are gone you may want to make repairs. If the over-coat paint was thin and if the stars peeled away nicely then you might get away with just another coat of paint. On the other hand, if there's much of a step in the paint film or if there's damage to the underlying surface then you may need to use a filler like drywall joint compound or topping to smooth things. As in all drywall repair if you use a filler then you'll need to also use a primer before progressing to the new finish coat.

Comment: I gave this one a shot, It was working, but there were just too many stars and the damage too extensive. I ended up modifying your final suggestion to get something that seems to have solved the problem, if not in the way i'd have liked.

Answer (score 1):

My kids did that in their rooms , I let them change colors and later we could still see the glow even with 2 layers of paint 1 of bins primer, we used my wife’s lady bug steamer, when they got good they came down with the paint and primer, no big deal I used topping mud to fill the depressions and repainted no more glow.

Comment: This is a really interesting idea! They just fell off with the steam? Do you think it was the heat, the water, or both? (I don't have a steamer to try this with at the moment, but was thinking of getting one anyway and this could make me do it.)

Comment: probably the heat, try a hot air gun.

Comment: Not sure possibility of both as the paint was somewhat sticky also.

Comment: Tried this, it worked on a couple of stars, but most of them stayed in place.